# Numpy: Difference between a[i][j] and a[i,j]

Tags: python, list, numpy

Coming from a Lists background in Python and that of programming languages like C++/Java, one is used to the notation of extracting elements using `a[i][j]` approach. But in `NumPy`, one usually does `a[i,j]`. Both of these would return the same result.

What is the fundamental difference between the two and which should be preferred?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The main difference is that `a[i][j]` first creates a view onto `a[i]` and then indexes into that view. On the other hand, `a[i,j]` indexes directly into `a`, making it faster:

```
In [9]: a = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

In [10]: %timeit a[123][456]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 586 ns per loop

In [11]: %timeit a[123,456]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 234 ns per loop
```

For this reason, I'd prefer the latter.