# numpy array slicing unxpected results

Tags: python, numpy

I don't understand the behavior below. numpy arrays can generally be accessed through indexing, so [:,1] should be equivalent to [:][1], or so I thought. Could someone explain why this is not the case?

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])  
>>> a[:,1]  
array([2, 5])  
>>> a[:][1]  
array([4, 5, 6])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two forms of indexing are not the same.  You should use `[i, j]` and not `[i][j]`.  Even where both work, the first will be faster (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505000/numpy-difference-between-aij-and-ai-j)).

Using two indices `[i][j]` is two operations.  It does the first index and then does the second on the result of the first operation.  `[:]` just returns the entire array, so your first one is equivalent to `array[1]`.  Since only one index is passed, it assumed to refer to the first dimension (rows), so this means "get row 1".  Using one compound index `[i, j]` is a single operation that uses both indexing conditions at once, so `array[:, 1]` returns "all rows,  column 1".

Answer (score 1):

[:] creates a copy of your list ...

so that is essentially the same as

```
array[1] == array[:][1]
```

which correctly returns in this case `[4,5,6]`

while `array[:,1]` says return the first column which is indeed `[2,5]`

eg

```
a = [
      [1,2,3],
      [4,5,6]
    ]
```

so as you can see column 0 (`a[:,0]` )would be `[1,4]` and column 2(`a[:,2]`) would be `[3,6]`

meanwhile`a[1]` refers to the row 1 (or [4,5,6])
and `a[0]` would be the 0 row (or [1,2,3])

Comment: So why, in the first case, is it not the same?
Does [:,] have a different meaning?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> a[:,1]
array([2, 5])
```

you select the second dimension (column of your matrix) and take the element 1 in this dimension. the same way, `a[:,0]` selects the first column, here `array([1,4])`, `a[:,2]` the third column.

As was previously said, `a[:]` copies your list (be a numpy array or a list).