# Performance issues using nested for loops for image processing

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have code, shown [here](https://github.com/wesleybowman/cgh/blob/master/cgh.py), that makes a computer generated hologram given an initial image. The image that the program is currently using can be found in the in the [image directory](https://github.com/wesleybowman/cgh).

My program takes approx. one minute to run, and that is for a 10x10 pixel A, that only has 14 spots that the nested for loops actually care about. The slow down is the in getComplexwave function:

```
 def getComplexwave():
    '''Iterate through every source point, and calculate the complex wave
contribution at each sampling pixel on the film.'''
    for o in xrange(objPointShape):
        print o+1

        for i in xrange(ipxShape):
            for j in xrange(ipyShape):
                dx=objectpoints[o][0] - ipx[0][i]
                dy=objectpoints[o][1] - ipy[0][j]
                dz=objectpoints[o][2]

                distance=np.sqrt(dx**2+dy**2+dz**2)
                complexwave=np.exp(1j*k*distance)

                hologram[i][j]=hologram[i][j]+complexwave
```

Can someone help me vectorize this, or at least make it to where it is faster? I am still fairly new to python.

Also, any other suggestions to make the code better will be much appreciated! The output should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIgoz.jpg).

[The profiling information](http://pastebin.com/rwxvhhS0) for those who want it. Note that this is only the first ten, and it is sorted by internal time.

Comment: a first point: if `objectpoints` and `ipx` are N dimensional numpy arrays your slicing can bring to errors [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627891/numpy-array-slicing-unxpected-results)

Comment: Just from a glance it looks like it might be hard to vectorize some of this. You might want to look into using Cython for this function, you will probably get a 100x speedup. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can definitely be vectorized. I have created a dummy set of data:

```
objPointShape = 100
objectpoints = np.random.rand(objPointShape, 3)
ipxShape = 100
ipx = np.random.rand(1, ipxShape)
ipyShape = 100
ipy = np.random.rand(1, ipyShape)
k = 1
hologram = np.zeros((ipxShape,ipyShape))
hologram = hologram+0j
```

And a vectorized version of your function. Mine returns the hologram, rather than storing it in the global `hologram`:

```
def vec_get_complex_wave():
    dx = objectpoints[:, 0, None] - ipx # shape (objPointShape, ipxShape)
    dy = objectpoints[:, 1, None] - ipy # shape (objPointShape, ipyShape)
    dz = objectpoints[:, 2, None] # shape (objPointShape, 1)
    distance = np.sqrt((dx*dx)[..., None] + (dy*dy)[:, None, :] +
                       (dz*dz)[..., None])
    complexwave = np.exp(1j*k*distance)
    return complexwave.sum(axis=0)
```

There is a significant performance increase of almost x150 faster for the above case of `objPointShape`, `ipxShape` and `ipyShape` all equal to 100:

```
%timeit -n1 -r1 getComplexwave()
1 loops, best of 1: 11.1 s per loop

%timeit vec_get_complex_wave()
10 loops, best of 3: 76.7 ms per loop

np.allclose(hologram, vec_get_complex_wave())
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: This is fantastic, and I have implimented it. Although, I am not quite getting it as fast as you did, my ipxShape=ipyShape=601, but my objPointShape is usually very small (i.e. 14).

Also, if the objPointShape is large (1000 or so) I get memory errors. Anyway to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know what is each thing, otherwise I'd need to read and understand your whole code before being able to contribute at all. In this case, what is ipxShape, ipyShape, objPointShape...

As I understand your code, one of the easiest things to vectorize is the distances from all the pixels to a given source, with coordinates (x0,y0). There is more than one way to do this, and I don't claim mine is particularly efficient, but to me the most intuitive is to build a matrix of distances in X, a matrix in distances in Y and add those contributions in quadrature, giving the distances.

```
import numpy as np
# Assuming values for image width, image height and source coordinates
xwidth = 10    # width of image in x direction
ywidth = 10    # Width of image in y direction
x0,y0 = 5,5    # assuming your source is in coordinates (5,5)

# Calculating distance in X and in Y direction for every pixel at once
x = np.matrix(range(xwidth)) - x0   
y = np.matrix(range(ywidth)).T - y0 
distX = np.ones((ywidth,1)) * x      # matrix of X distances 
distY = y * np.ones(xwidth)       # matrix of Y distances
distance = np.sqrt(np.multiply(distX,distX) + np.multiply(distY,distY))

# Now you can do the exponential of all the elements at one
complexwave = np.exp(1j*k*distance)  # whatever k is... 

# And now the hologram is:
hologram = hologram + complexwave
```

Greetings!