# Grab all the x values from stacked array? Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I got a list of 2x1 arrays containing x,y coordinates. 
So it looks like `[np.array([x,y]), np.array([x,y]), np.array([x,y]), ...]`

Now I want a list or array which will contain all the x values and one for all the y values.
But doing things like `list[:][1]` does not work.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [numpy array slicing unxpected results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627891/numpy-array-slicing-unxpected-results)

Comment: Could I ask how you wound up with that data structure?  If you have control over it and could use a 2D array instead, then `x,y = list_2d.T` would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L = [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4]), np.array([5, 6])]
>>> X = [a[0] for a in L]
>>> Y = [a[1] for a in L]
>>> X
[1, 3, 5]
>>> Y
[2, 4, 6]
```

As @DSM noted, you can transpose the list as well:

```
>>> X, Y = map(list, zip(*L))
>>> X
[1, 3, 5]
>>> Y
[2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Another option is `X = map(lambda a: a[0], L)`.

Comment: @DSM submit that as an answer, it's better