# How can I detect if a value in a DataFrame crosses another value in the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, candlestick-chart

This is a sample of my DataFrame which is quite large. It is candlestick OHLC data with some additional columns 'Target' etc.

```
                             Open      High  ...      Target  
Close Time                                   ...                     
2022-05-23 06:59:59.999  30301.46  30655.00  ...         NaN      
2022-05-23 07:59:59.999  30487.77  30670.51  ...         NaN      
2022-05-23 08:59:59.999  30457.01  30523.51  ...         NaN     
2022-05-23 09:59:59.999  30345.73  30520.00  ...    30520.00      
2022-05-23 10:59:59.999  30441.94  30519.28  ...         NaN
```

How can I check if the price of this particular asset crosses over the target price after that target price was initially hit.

So the 'Target' time is 2022-05-23 09:59:59.999 and this candlestick data is in 1 hour timeframes. the price is currently moving up however say 10 hours later the price moves back down and touches the same price as the 'Target'.

There are many targets in the DataFrame and I want to be able to detect price crossing the target regardless of the direction of the price movement

How can I determine if this happens and how can I then make this particular 'Target' value NaN?

I've tried something like this but can't get it to work

```
for i in range(len(df['Open'])):
    if df['High'][i:] < df['Target'][i]:
        if df['High'][i:] > df['Target'][i]:
            print('Target hit')
```

I get `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Notice in the plotted candlestick chart the 'Target' price (blue triangle) is passed again in the future candles. This is what I am trying to detect and remove the target from df once it has been hit.
[image]

Comment: When you say "price of this particular asset crosses over the target price after that target price was initially hit", does that mean checking whether `(Open) < (Target) < (Close)`?

Comment: Yeah that's essentially correct, however, it would be (Open) < (Target) < (High) to capture any spikes in the price even if the close is below the target

Comment: I don't know why "High" became "Close" when I typed that out... makes sense, at any rate

Comment: Is the `:` in `df['High'][i:]` intentional?

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what you're trying to do, but it sounds like a useful intermediate step would be to make another column that gives the index of the first row where that target is exceeded, and another column that gives the first index of the first row *after the target was exceeded* where the value at close falls below the target

Comment: @BenGrossmann I added a visual of what I'm trying to do, hopefully it clarifies it a little

Comment: So if a target is ever exceeded after the timestamp of that target, then you want to set that target to `nan`. Is that correct? Is that everything that you're trying to do?

Comment: Also, it there any logic to the coloring of the candles here?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.
Green candles = 'Open' < 'Close' Red candles = 'Open > 'Close"

Comment: I swear I knew that haha. Thanks for explaining, I think it all makes sense now

Comment: Do you also have a `Low` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, assuming you also have a "Low" column.

```
## generate example dataframe ##
from numpy import nan
d = {'Open': {'06:59:59.999': 30301.46, '07:59:59.999': 30487.77, '08:59:59.999': 30457.01, '09:59:59.999': 30345.73, '10:59:59.999': 30441.94}, 
     'High': {'06:59:59.999': 30655.0, '07:59:59.999': 30670.51, '08:59:59.999': 30523.51, '09:59:59.999': 30520.0, '10:59:59.999': 30519.28}, 
     'Target': {'06:59:59.999': 30600.0, '07:59:59.999': 30600.0, '08:59:59.999': 30500.0, '09:59:59.999': 30521.0, '10:59:59.999': 30500.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df["Low"] = df["Open"]

## find 'Target' values that need to be NaN'ed ##
idx_high,idx_low,idx_targ = map(df.columns.get_loc,["High","Low","Target"])
row_bool = [
            ((df.iloc[i:,idx_high] > df.iat[i,idx_targ])
                &(df.iloc[i:,idx_low] < df.iat[i,idx_targ])
            ).any() for i in range(len(df))
           ]

## set those values to NaN ##
df.loc[row_bool,"Target"] = np.nan
```

For the particular example I constructed, we start with

```
                  Open      High   Target       Low
06:59:59.999  30301.46  30655.00  30600.0  30301.46
07:59:59.999  30487.77  30670.51  30600.0  30487.77
08:59:59.999  30457.01  30523.51  30500.0  30457.01
09:59:59.999  30345.73  30520.00  30521.0  30345.73
10:59:59.999  30441.94  30519.28  30500.0  30441.94
```

and end up with

```
                  Open      High   Target       Low
06:59:59.999  30301.46  30655.00      NaN  30301.46
07:59:59.999  30487.77  30670.51      NaN  30487.77
08:59:59.999  30457.01  30523.51      NaN  30457.01
09:59:59.999  30345.73  30520.00  30521.0  30345.73
10:59:59.999  30441.94  30519.28      NaN  30441.94
```

---

I suspect that the following is a bit faster.

```
## find 'Target' values that need to be NaN'ed ##
row_bool = [
            ((df.loc[idx:,"High"] > row["Target"])
                &(df.loc[idx:,"Low"] < row["Target"])
            ).any() for idx,row in df.iterrows()
           ]

## set those values to NaN ##
df.loc[row_bool,"Target"] = np.nan
```

Interestingly (to me), this means that the whole thing can be done with a single (not very readable) line of code:

```
df.loc[[((df.loc[idx:,"High"] > row["Target"])&(df.loc[idx:,"Low"] < row["Target"])).any() for idx,row in df.iterrows()],"Target"] = np.nan
```

Comment: @Callum If you're curious about why I used `df.iloc[i:,idx_high]` rather than `df['High'][i:]` (which indeed yields the same result) like you did in your script, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16505000/2476977).

Comment: thanks heaps, you've been super helpful, I've been able to make your code work for me. I'll check out the post you linked to, I need to get my head around this as I'll be using it a lot

Comment: @Callum You're welcome. I'm curious by the way, what changes did you have to make to get this to work?

Comment: it was actually a more complex issue than I originally thought and so your code worked as it should have but didn't totally solve the issue. Instead of 'Target' being a single point it was actually a range (recorded in the DataFrame by 2 numbers, the high and low point of the range, i.e 'target top' and 'target bottom') so when using your code sometimes that range wasn't covered by a single candle and therefore wasn't given the np.nan value (Hope that makes sense)